# ¿Existe el usuario o es Administrador? ¿Cómo hacer un middleware con ésto?

Tags: laravel

os pongo en situación.

Tengo una aplicación típica donde existe el rol de usuario y el rol de administración.

A algunos métodos (Crear un producto, editarlo, borrarlo...etc) Solo tendrían permiso los administrador mientras que, para ver estos productos, comprarlos...etc tendría permiso el usuario.

He creado un código que funciona a la perfección y es éste:

```
if (\Auth::user()==null) {
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }elseif (\Auth::user()->role != 'admin') {
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
```

Esto me comprobaría en cada método que quisiese si el usuario está logueado y si lo está comprobaría si es administrador. El caso es que, es un poco engorroso incluir este método en **CADA UNO** de los métodos.

¿Alguna solución un poco más practica? He probado a usarlo en un helper pero he comprobado que no puedo incluir métodos estáticos y bajo un middleware no me funciona (tal vez no lo haya implementado bien)

Comment: ¿Agregarías tu código de lo último que indicas haber intentado?

Comment: Revisa la edición que acabo de hacer @BetaM

Comment: Ya conseguí solucionarlo @BetaM Ahora escribo respuesta con el código

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es más fácil de lo que pensaba.

Incluir en el constructor de la clase del Controlador:

```
$this->middleware('auth');
```

Este middleware ya viene hecho al general los Auth con Laravel y así puedes implementarlo.

Si quieres exceptuar algunos métodos:

```
$this->middleware('auth')->except('metodo)';
```

Para hacerlo con el Administrador:

```
php artisan make:middleware IsAdmin
```

Y dentro de handle escribimos:

```
if(Auth::user()->role == 'admin'){
            return $next($request);
        }else{
            return redirect()->route('home');
        }
```

**(En este caso, la propiedad de mi tabla que comprueba si un usuario es administrador es 'role')**

Añadimos el middleware en el archivo Kernel que está en App\Http

(lo metemos dentro del array $routeMiddleware)

```
'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\IsAdmin::class,
```

Con esto ya estaría. Ahora únicamente llamamos al middleware en nuestro constructor

```
$this->middleware('admin');
```